# How to enable HTML table scrolling on a single column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm starting to develop an HTML/Javascript/jquery application.

I have an HTML table with 100 rows and 5 columns.

I can display only 10 rows of this table on my device, so I need to scroll up and down on this table to display all values.

In order to do this, I need to enable scrolling only on the middle column. With the scroll event on the middle column, the table should scroll normally.

With the scroll event on other column, the table shouldn't scroll.

Furthermore, the table has a header and a footer. These elements must be fixed on table scroll.

Can you post some idea or piece of code to do that?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: you might consider pagination with https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply toggle `overflow-y` values `auto / hidden` when a desired column is hovered

```js
var $container = $("#container");

$container.find("td").hover(function(){
  $container.toggleClass("oyScroll", $(this).index() == 1);
});
```

```css
#container {
  height:170px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#container.oyScroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
table {
  width:100%;
}
table td {
  background:#eee;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```